# Will a 54-507 inner tube work with a 50-559 tyre?

Tags: innertube, tyre-width

I need to replace the inner tube on my bicycle tyre.

The tyre i have has these numbers printed on it:

**26x2.0 50-559**

Numbers on the inner tube:

**26x2.125 (57-507)**

**26x1.95/2.10 (54-507)**

I am not sure if they are compatible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** sorry.  507mm is a 24" wheel, and 559mm is a 26" wheel.

Your existing tyre is 559mm so your rim is also that size, and thus your tubes have to fit it.

Good news is that 559mm is a common size and is more-common than 507 or 24" which is somewhat-unusual.

Comment: Alright, learnt something new in the process. The weirdest thing is that the package says 26" and the size numbers next to it say something else.  Imma just open it up, take the risk that the tube inside has proper numbering.

Comment: @MellowMonk even if it's 24", you can probably get way with it. I bought a 2nd hand bike with 26" wheels and found out months later when I upgraded my tyres that one of the tubed was 24"

Comment: @MellowMonk one of those two numbers is wrong.  Either the 26inch or the 507mm.   I guess you have a 50% chance of getting the tube you need.